# binding MultiSelectionModel to checkBoxColumn in CellTable, but why checkBoxs in column were not AUTO-selected CORRESPONDINGLY to SelectionModel?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Here is my problem.
I have simple table with 3 columns (Id, no, text) Id and no combination creates a unique key for each row.

```
Id - no - text
12 - 1 - my text1
12 - 2 - my text2
13 - 1 - cool
13 - 2 - cool2
13 - 3 - cool3
```

Now, i want to load these data into a CellTable with 4 columns (the 1st column is checkBoxColumn, the other 3 columns are ID/No/Text textcolum. I also want to put a SelectAllCheckBox on the Header of checkBoxColumn so that when user click on selectAllCheckBox then all the current visible checkBoxes got selected (of cause celltable could have many page but it will select only the visible ones).

Here is the code, i finished all the requirements except 1, that is "when i clicked the selectAllCheckBox, the `selectionModel` got selected but the correspondingly checkBoxes were not selected.

Here is the Code.

```
public static final ProvidesKey<String[]> KEY_PROVIDER = new ProvidesKey<String[]>() {
      @Override
      public Object getKey(String[] item) {
        String[] itemArr={item[0],item[1]};
        return item == null ? null : itemArr;

      }
};
```

Here is the main CellTable  code:

```
final MultiSelectionModel<String[]> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<String[]>(KEY_PROVIDER);

final CellTable<String[]> cellTable = new CellTable<String[]>();

Column<String[], Boolean> checkColumn = new Column<String[], Boolean>(
                new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(String[] object) {
                // Get the value from the selection model.
                 String[] objectArr={object[0],object[1]};

                 return selectionModel.isSelected(objectArr);



         }
 };

 cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
 CheckboxHeader selectAllCheckBoxHeader = new CheckboxHeader();
 selectAllCheckBoxHeader.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("test");
                for (String[] item : cellTable.getVisibleItems()) {


                    if (!selectionModel.isSelected(item)) {
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item));
                      selectionModel.setSelected(item, true);

                    }
                }
            }

  });
  cellTable.addColumn(checkColumn, selectAllCheckBoxHeader);
```

When I clikced the selectAll, then non of visible checkBoxes got check, but when printout

```
Set<String[]> selSet=selectionModel.getSelectedSet();
for(String[] s : selSet){
  System.out.println("Mine: "+Arrays.toString(s));
}
```

it showed the currect selected items

Suppose pageSize is 3, then 
Output :

```
Mine: [12,1,my text1]
Mine: [12,2,my text2]
Mine: [13,1,cool]
```

So how to make visible checkBoxes got selected automatically EXACTLY and CORESPONDINGLY /In TANDEM as the `selectionModel` got selected

Note: I also tried `cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<String[]> createCheckboxManager());` but not working.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed
first, just use `item[]`

```
public Object getKey(String[] item) {
     return item == null ? null : item;
}
```

& then

```
public Boolean getValue(String[] object) {
     return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
}
```

then use

```
cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<String[]> createCheckboxManager());
```

Finally, it works as i expected